# Unable to Update SQLite DB row in Android Studio Flamingo Database Inspector

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, database-inspector

I have updated android studio to flamingo. I am facing issue in opening database connection in database inspector. [image]

If I stop the process then database connections are opened but then I am unable to edit tables because of read-only mode in offline. I want to edit rows in database inspector.

I was using android studio arctic fox and it was working perfectly but in flamingo I am facing this issue. Any help?